# How to swap strings within strings with other strings without replace methods

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

So ok here's the what's up.  I need to create a method that accepts three variables as an argument (a, b, and c) and somehow swaps string c with string b which is in string a.

This has to be done WITHOUT the replace methods as that's the point of creating this method.

So examples would be

```
"Hello my friend, how are you?", "h", "y"
Result: "Yello my friend, yow are you?"
```

or

```
"Computer programming is great!", "great", "awesome"
Result: "Computer programming is awesome!"
```

We are given `charAt()`, `string.substring`, `string.length()`, and `string.IndexOf()` to solve this. Any ideas?

Comment: I also want to know the answer. Let me know when you get one!

Comment: Why don't you try something/fiddle around with the results of those 4 statements to get something working?

Comment: [Yes I have an idea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: i will give you a hint, have a look at code for method   `replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` in String class, but i won't do your homework for you

Comment: Is it case sensitive replacement also?

Comment: No doing my homework for me is ill advised, my problem with this class is I can write code, I just don't really know exactly what it does sometimes.

Comment: I do believe it is case sensitive but that's the luxury details I can work on after I get the exchange to be made in the first place

Comment: OK I have posted my answer with case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `regex`.

```
    StringBuffer myStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    // find all h or H
    Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("h|H");
    Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher("Hello my friend, how are you?");
    while (myMatcher.find()) {
        // replace all the occurrence with the actual replacement
        if (myMatcher.group().equals("h")) {
            myMatcher.appendReplacement(myStringBuffer, "y");
        } else {
            myMatcher.appendReplacement(myStringBuffer, "Y");
        }
    }
    myMatcher.appendTail(myStringBuffer);
    System.out.println(myStringBuffer);
```

output:

```
Yello my friend, yow are you?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that writing exact code is not right since this is clearly school assignment.
This is very easy task and after reading  [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) you should have idea how to implement it.
If not heres little hint

```
You have to chceck wheter string b is substring of a if yes split a into two strings without b and put c between them.
```

All this can be done using methods you mentioned